# How can we convert video files to .flv format in php

Tags: php

Hi I have to convert video files to .flv format in php. any body have any simple scripts please give me.

Answer (score 6):

with help of [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)

Comment: hi I created like this but its not working

ffmpeg -i /shob testing video.MPG -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 /FLV/shob testing video.flv

Comment: add anything you've tried to the initial question: the complete command and part of the output with error.

Answer (score 3):

check this out.. this code should work

```
    <?php
class media_handler
{
function convert_media($filename, $rootpath, $inputpath, $outputpath, $width, $height, $bitrate, $samplingrate)
{
$outfile = "";
// root directory path, where FFMPEG folder exist in your application.
$rPath = $rootpath."\ffmpeg";
// which shows FFMPEG folder exist on the root.
// Set Media Size that is width and hieght
$size = $width."x".$height;
// remove origination extension from file adn add .flv extension, becuase we must give output file name to ffmpeg command.
$outfile =$filename;
$out=explode(".",$outfile);


// Media Size
//$size = Width & "x" & Height;

// remove origination extenstion from file and add .flv extension , becuase we must give output filename to ffmpeg command.

$outfile = $out[0].".flv";
// Use exec command to access command prompt to execute the following FFMPEG Command and convert video to flv format.

$ffmpegcmd1 = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i ".$inputpath."/".$filename. " -ar " .$samplingrate." -ab ".$bitrate." -f flv -s ".$size." ".$outputpath."/".$outfile;

//$ffmpegcmd1 = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i ".$inputpath."/".$filename. " -b 500 -r 25 -s 320×240 -hq -deinterlace -ab 56 -ar 22050 -ac 1 ".$outputpath."/".$outfile." 2>&1";


$ret = shell_exec($ffmpegcmd1);

// return output file name for other operations
return $ffmpegcmd1;
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

include_once("media_handler.php");

$_objMda    =   new mandler();
//$_objMda as new mandler();

$rootpath ="";
$nputpath = $rootpath."/Default";
$outputpath = $rootpath. "/FLV";
$ThumbPath = $rootpath. "/Thumbs";

if($_POST){ 
//Save original video in Default folder.

$source = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['file1']['size']; 
$filetype = $_FILES['file1']['type']; 
$dest = '';

copy($source, $inputpath . $name);

// Convert it into FLV Format

$outfile = $_objMda->convert_media($name,$rootpath, $inputpath, $outputpath, 320, 240, 32, 22050);

I used ur class but no result sir. can I set any thing on my phpini for doing this?