# How can I convert all video file to FLV format in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can we convert video files to .flv format in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918713/how-can-we-convert-video-files-to-flv-format-in-php)

How to convert any video file to FLV using PHP? What are the system requirements? Currently I am using WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) That is the standard software for dynamic video conversion from one format to another. 
 
 Hope this helps.